# Show users selection before submitting form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Hi I will like to show the names of the files selected to the user in the return confirmation button before submission.Here is my code so far.How do I call a php function from the return confirmation button?Any suggestions will be appreciated

```
<form method ="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" > 
<?php    
  echo "<ul>"; 
  foreach($dir as $item){    
    $items = basename($item);
    $str = str_replace("+"," ",$items);
    if(strpos($str,'test') === false){
      if(strlen($str)==3){
        $strs = ucwords(strtoupper($str));
        echo "<li><input type = 'checkbox' class='check-class' name='chk[]' id=$strs value=$item >$strs<br>";
      }
      #echo ucwords(strtoupper($str));
      else{
        $strs = ucwords($str);
        echo "<li><input type='checkbox' class='check-class' name='chk[]' id=$strs value=$item>$strs<br>";
      }
      #echo ucwords($str);
      echo "</li>";
    }
  }

  echo "</ul>";
?>


<div style="text-align:center"><button name="Deploy" type="submit"      style="font-face:'Comic Sams MS';font-size:larger;color:red;background-color:#FAF0E6;border:3pt ridge lightgrey" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to exclude these folders?.Folders Selected:')"  value="submit">Initiate Deployment</button>  </div> </div> </form>
```

Comment: You will have to use JavaScript and AJAX.

Comment: You would be better off handling this with Javascript then using an ajax request to call PHP code.

Comment: you tagged this as jquery but you aren't using any so far. May a `$('button').click(function() { });` is what you need instead of the onclick attribute in the button